# Submitting app with base SDK iOS 6.1 to App Store while iOS 7.0 is out

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7

*Disclaimer: I'm comparably new to iOS development.*

We just ended coding our app for **iOS 5.0 to 6.1** and we're ready to submit it. However, iOS 7 is now out and we don't have time to redesign the whole application.

I updated my IDE to **xCode 5** and then copied **iOS 6.1 SDK** so I can set the **Base SDK to iOS 6.1**. However, when I build the app for iOS 7.0 simulator, it's all iOS 7.0 look and feel again.

Is there a way to submit the app to App Store that runs with **iOS 6.1** look and feel, even if the user's device has **iOS 7.0** installed?

Answer (score 1):

Running your app compiled with the iOS 6.1 SDK should run it in 'iOS6 Compatibility Mode' on iOS6. This means your app will use *some* of the iOS6 controls, but not all of them.

For example: The UINavigationController will look and work like iOS6, as will the keyboards, DatePickers, and UISwitches.

However, Alert dialogs will be iOS7, as will a couple of other things like (annoyingly) UISegmentedControls.

Also, if you have used default-styled Round Rect UIButtons, on iOS7 they'll appear just as text (no rounded background).

Answer (score 1):

You need to download again XCode 4.5 with SDK for iOS 6.1. And use that XCode to build and submit your application.

Answer (score 1):

I quote the following from Ben answer:

> However, Alert dialogs will be iOS7, as will a couple of other things
>   like (annoyingly) UISegmentedControls.

If more than these controls are having the look and feel of iOS 7.0 and you don't like that. then, go with Sha answer. and reinstall Xcode 4.5.

**My personal experience**

> I built my app with XCode 4.5 and sdk 6.1 and published my apps and
>   it's working perfectly on iOS 7.0 with the look and feel of 6.1 except
>   the Alert Dialogs as Ben said.
>
> I downloaded xCode 5.0 and built with sdk 7.0 but my problem was more
>   than a look and feel. my app. crashed. I didn't copy sdk 6.1 as you did so I didn't
>   experience what you have. and can't tell if building with Xcode 5.0
>   and Build with sdk 6.1 will have **all** the look and feel of 7.0 iOS on iOS
>   7.0. I personally can't see that at all.
>
> If you really have this problem. Go with re-installing XCode 4.5 and
>   it will work. I did exactly the same downgraded XCode and SDK. then
>   published and all worked just fine.

I can't understand how is the XCode version and not the SDK version have anything to do with the look and feel as Sha said.